# Active Directory Management Tool

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am curious to see what other third party tools people are using to administer Windows AD.  My own research has found Quest and NetIQ seem to be front runners.  Any others? Any experience or Pro/Con list of why NetIQ or Quest makes good/bad tools?

I am specifically looking for tools to manage users and create reports for things like SOX/PCI and various inane management requests ("Can you tell me all the phone numbers for users with the letter Z in their name")

Comment: Here's a very similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/30002/are-there-any-good-and-lightweight-ldap-querying-tools

Comment: Thanks for the add on.  Not exactly what I am looking for, but perhaps someone will find that looking at my question who does need it.

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory management tool from Softerra.

Softerra Adaxes (http://adaxes.com)

Comment: adaxes has made it into my final three!  We will be demoing it soon.  Do you have any personal experience with the product?

Comment: Yes it is a nice tool. We like Softerra's support best of all. With their set of features they have a competitive price. That was a huge plus while making a decision.

Answer (score 1):

[Hyena](http://www.systemtools.com/hyena/)

Answer (score 0):

[SCRIPTING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd793613)!  I'm a huge fan of AD/LDAP scripting