# Best free utility to write and execute a LDAP query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good and lightweight LDAP querying tools?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30002/are-there-any-good-and-lightweight-ldap-querying-tools)

Best free utility to write and execute a LDAP query.
I'm running windows

Comment: ldp.exe -> http://serverfault.com/questions/30002/are-there-any-good-and-lightweight-ldap-querying-tools/30008#30008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [Softerra LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/).